# Problem publishing content in Experience Manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, session-preview

I have found a possible error publishing content in Experience Manager with the **Finish Editing** button.

The problem is that I have made some changes in the content of my Page and when I click **Finish Editing** I would like to see this changes in the Staging/Preview Web Site, so I open a new tab on the same browser and I can see my changes, but if I open the same page in a different browser I can't see it.

Is it the correct behavior? Is there something wrong in some file like `cd_ambient`?

**EDIT 1**
If a change a single Component and then click the Finish Editing button I can see in the Publishing Queue that the Component is correctly published and in the CME the changes have been applied too, but the problem continues.

Comment: After clicking **Finish Editing** the changes should be saved and the Page (or Component you edited) should be published. Can you check in the CME if your changes are indeed saved and if Publishing of those changes were successful? Please **edit** your question and add this updated information in there which will help in getting relevant answers.

Comment: If the new tab has Experience Manager running (and it's before the page is published) then it's likely Session Preview is showing you the results of the latest session (same browser session). But a different browser will have a different session, so it'll only show if you manually click Update Preview or after the changes are published.

Answer (score 1):

If your changes are successfully published, then your staging website should be updated, so regardless of XPM, you should be able to see the changes on your staging site.

If you don't (that is what you mention, you are not seeing the changes) then it sounds like the target that is being published too, is not the same as the actual staging site, or there is a caching issue on the staging site.

Not much of an answer, but based on the information given, hopefully a nudge in the right direction.